# Need help figuring out how to write this Regex properly

Tags: javascript, regex, hex

I am trying to make a regex test that returns true for the following conditions:

- Can only have letters A-F (case insensitive)
- First character must be '#'
- Can have numbers 0-9
- Does not have punctuation

The order does not matter except that string[0] should be '#'.

So far I have: `/^#[A-F0-9^!G-Z]/i`
but for some reason, it returns strings that have letters after F (like G or J) as true.

Comment: In short, your regex can be like this: `/^#[A-F0-9]*/`. If you want your regex unmatch letters from G-Z, it should be written like this: `[^G-Z]`

Comment: @NekoMi Your regex is correct so he doesn't need to write `[^G-Z]` because in your first regexp you already specify the range of letters

Comment: `/^#[0-9A-F]*$/i` to be case-insensitive and force it to match the entire string

Comment: Good idea with the /i flag ~ the only reason I did the ^G-Z part is because it was still returning strings with letters after F as true...

Anyway thanks for all of your help! It was very helpful and I feel like I know regex a bit better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^#[0-9A-Fa-f]*$
```

Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `#` - a hash symbol
- `[0-9A-Fa-f]*` - zero or more hex chars (note it can be written as `[[:xdigit:]]*` in some regex flavors, but not in ECMAScript flavor used in JavaScript)
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!! Especially for the explanation. It all works now. My only q still is, why is the $ at the end necessary?

Comment: @mrspoopybutthole Otherwise, there can be anythin else after zero or more xdigit chars.